# Microsoft Access Blank isn't Blank

Tags: ms-access

I've come across an issue with a table I've been working with. I've linked a small segment of it below.

[image: Table]

The problem is that when I right click on leave_date and select Equals Blank, it only returns the fourth row. Similarly, if I select Does Not Equal Blank it returns all but the fourth row.

Investigating further, if I apply this to the whole table it returns around 470 of the 33000 rows, which is quite infuriating!

Both the cells are **definitely** blank but Access doesn't see it this way!

Thanks,

Comment: Blank doesn't necessarily mean empty. An empty string will appear blank but there is still something there. Whereas Null really is blank and empty - nothing there. However, you show this happening with a date value. Is this a date/time type field?

Comment: Just did test, Null and empty string are both treated as Blank so there must be some other non-printable character involved. Which should be possible only in a text type field.

Comment: @June7 is right. Your fields are not of data type _Date_ but text, and are set to _allow zero length strings_. Change to the fields to Date, and they can only hold a valid date or _Null_.

Comment: Also, you show leave_date values as non-Access standard structure although join_date do appear to be standard.